# Removed ability to run sudo commands on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, root

I did something pretty stupid - while struggling to add sudo power to a user on my Ubuntu system, I changed the following line in /etc/sudoers:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As a result of this, *none* of my users have sudo ability, and I think the root password is unset (the default Ubuntu configuration). Is there anything I can do to get sudo access back?

EDIT: I did use sudo visudo to make the edit, which I thought was supposed to prevent me from doing anything too stupid...but not everything I guess!

Comment: Boot from a live-cd and use the rescue shell to mount your drive and edit the file. Also, there are commands for editing sudo-ers that are designed to check your edits to prevent this sort of "stupid"... Read up on them. Use them.

Comment: See my edit - I tried to, but didn't know enough what I was doing. Lesson learned, and I will try your fix for sure.

Comment: @C.M. `visudo` can only check if the sudoers file is syntactically correct.  It can't read minds or know whether a syntactically correct sudoers file is what the user actually wants.   It can not protect against mistakes like this.   Setting a password for root can (i.e. it allows you to use `su` to fix it), so it's advisable to do that even if it's unfashionable and modern distros recommend against it.

Comment: True... I have not used `visudo` myself in a long time--I use hand written TCL scripts for systems administration editing, which check much more. For the benefit of others who come across this, I also suggest you make versioned or timestamped backups of system files before editing, such as `sudo.conf.20210624.v3`. (In my case, I even have several template files that get added together to make the full file, similar to how `grub` and `resolveconf` work.)

Comment: If the root password is unset (the Ubuntu default) then you can simply boot into recovery mode, drop to a root shell, `mount -o remount,rw /` and then edit the sudoers file with `visudo`

Comment: If the root password is set, you can just run `su` and fix /etc/sudoers without needing to reboot.

Comment: @cas: I don't know the root password; I would guess it is unset.

Comment: @steeldriver Your fix worked - if you want to answer this question with it I will give you credit! (on the other hand, no upvotes so maybe not worth it. Your call!)